# Buscar posición en lista e imprimir 2 números anteriores al que salio

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sale un numero aleatorio llamado bola , busco la posición en la lista NumerosTotalesRuleta y quiero imprimir los dos anteriores al que salio teniendo en cuenta el orden en el que están en la lista , por ejemplo si sale el 4 pues me imprimiría el 15.

Parece funcionar bien como lo hice pero el problema lo tengo si sale por ejemplo el 32 ya que no hay anteriores y si sale el 32 me gustaría que imprimera el 26 ya que son anteriores comenzando por la cola (son números en una ruleta, un circulo vamos).

de paso me gusatria que en cada tirada se imprimera una variable junto a los dos numeros anteriores del que salio, primero A en el siguiente turno B luego otra vez A, asi de paso aprendo a realizar esto también.

ejemplos de uso

Sale el 14 imprimiria "1A"
luego sale el 14 otra vez, imprimira 1B
luego sale el 15 pues  imprimira 0A

espero que se entienda , mil gracias

P.D Ya se que parece absurdo el ejercicio , no le busquéis el sentido pero con esto aprendo.

```
NumerosTotalesRuleta=[32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,
8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,
22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26,0]

def Principal():
    bola=(random.randint(0,36))

    posicion=(NumerosTotalesRuleta.index(int(bola))-2)

    print (NumerosTotalesRuleta[posicion])

    time.sleep(5)

while 1==1:
    Principal()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> el problema lo tengo si sale por ejemplo el 32 ya que no hay anteriores y si sale el 32 me gustaría que imprimera el 26 ya que son anteriores comenzando por la cola (son números en una ruleta, un circulo vamos).

Pues no tienes ese problema, ya lo hace... Python permite indizado negativo, `numeros_totales_ruleta.index(32) - 2` retorna -2 y el -2 es el antepenúltimo elemento de la lista (26)...

> ```
> >>> numeros_totales_ruleta[numeros_totales_ruleta.index(32) - 2]
> 26
>
> >>> numeros_totales_ruleta[numeros_totales_ruleta.index(15) - 2]
> 0
> ```

En cuanto a la segunda duda, el problema básicamente es que necesitas almacenar la letra usada anteriormente para que en cada llamada a la función puedas cambiarla. El unir la letra al número es trivial, simplemente usar formateo de cadenas. Tienes varias posibilidades:

- Sacar el `print` de la función y usar dos variables globales que se intercambien valores:

  ```
  def principal():
      bola = random.randint(0, 36)
      posicion = numeros_totales_ruleta.index(bola) - 2
      return posicion


  letra_1 = "a"
  letra_2 = "b"
  while True:
      num = principal()
      print(f"{letra_1}{num}")
      letra_1, letra_2 = letra_2, letra_1
      time.sleep(5)
  ```
- Igual que antes pero usando variables globales dentro de la función (deben evitarse su uso de ser posible por lo general):

  ```
  letra_1 = "a"
  letra_2 = "b"
  def principal():
      global letra_1
      global letra_2
      bola = random.randint(0, 36)
      posicion = numeros_totales_ruleta.index(bola) - 2
      print(f"{letra_1}{numeros_totales_ruleta[posicion]}")
      letra_1, letra_2 = letra_2, letra_1
      time.sleep(5)

  while True:
      principal()
  ```
- Usando `itertools.cycle`

  ```
  import itertools

  def principal():
      bola = random.randint(0, 36)
      posicion = numeros_totales_ruleta.index(bola) - 2
      return posicion


  letras = itertools.cycle("ab")
  while True:
      num = principal()
      print(f"{next(letras)}{num}")
      time.sleep(5)
  ```

  Podrías también usarlo desde dentro de la función, pero debes llamar `cycle` fuera.
- También puedes emular a `itertools.cycle`:

  ```
  def principal():
      bola = random.randint(0, 36)
      posicion = numeros_totales_ruleta.index(bola) - 2
      return posicion


  letras = "ab"
  letra = 0
  while True:
      num = principal()
      print(f"{letras[letra]}{num}")
      letra = (letra + 1) % len(letras)
      time.sleep(5)
  ```
- Para mantener el estado, también puedes usar una función generadora:

  ```
  import random
  import time

  numeros_totales_ruleta = [
      32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34, 6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10, 5, 24,
      16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9, 22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26, 0
      ]


  def bolas_gen():
      letras = "ab"
      letra = 0
      while True:
          bola = random.randint(0, 36)
          posicion = numeros_totales_ruleta.index(bola) - 2
          res = f"{letras[letra]}{numeros_totales_ruleta[posicion]}"
          yield res
          letra = (letra + 1) % len(letras)



  for bola in bolas_gen(): # ¡Generador infinito!
      print(bola)
      time.sleep(5)
  ```
- Usar una clase:

  ```
  import itertools
  import random
  import time


  class Ruleta:
      numeros_totales_ruleta = [
          32, 15, 19, 4, 21, 2, 25, 17, 34, 6, 27, 13, 36, 11, 30, 8, 23, 10,
          5, 24, 16, 33, 1, 20, 14, 31, 9, 22, 18, 29, 7, 28, 12, 35, 3, 26, 0
          ]

      def __init__(self, letras="ab"):
          self.letras = letras
          self.letras_gen = itertools.cycle(letras)

      def tirar(self):
          bola = random.randint(0, 36)
          posicion = self.numeros_totales_ruleta.index(bola) - 2
          res = f"{next(self.letras_gen)}{self.numeros_totales_ruleta[posicion]}"
          return res


  ruleta = Ruleta()
  while True:
      print(ruleta.tirar())
      time.sleep(5)
  ```

Y hay muchas más posibilidades...

Dos observaciones:

- Para generar un ciclo infinito, basta con que hagas `while True` o en todo caso `while 1`.
- `random.randint` ya retorna un `int`, no hace falta un casting explícito `int(bola)`.

Comment: Es genial, gracias por tu dedicación! me sirve de mucho